# How To Specify A Site Collection To Use A Specific Search Service Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, enterprise-search, search-scope

My SharePoint 2013 farm has two search services. I want different site collections to use a specific search service.

Im not sure if this is the correct/best way but I was thinking of creating a site collection result source, set it as the default source. In the result source using the query builder set the property filter for ServiceApplicationID to the ID of the search service?

Is this correct or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: What requirement has driven you create 2 Search Service Applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many site collections are we talking about? Why do you have two search service applications?

If you want to have a split on search service application's usage, then its better to have it at web application level from a logical architecture perspective.

*Central admin -> Application Management -> Service Application Association* page to identify service application association with appropriate web application. Then again, you might need to re-consider two web applications decision in favor of host-named site collections.

If you don't do above, you can still manage to get away with creating result sources at service application level and refer them in the site collection using their GUIDs to filter results.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. The reason for the two search service applications is for legal reasons. We have two separate entities that deal with subpoenas. I know with having two site collections I can still give the two eDiscovery sites different host headers and store them in different databases, but its more then that. Even the index component cant have the indexed data of the two eDiscovery sites mixed, also any search settings/data has to be stored separately in different databases. However this needs to be all on one farm. Thanks for the help :)